# Ical sync dynamically with google calender

Tags: php, icalendar

I have created iCal event by using iCalcreator. I want to make the google calendar so that it syncs automatically. I can create the .ical file that I will be importing or adding by URL. After I login into Gmail it is working. How can I make my events to automatically add to calendar by using the URL dynamically?

Comment: AFAIK, this is impossible because without being logged in, the system/app has no idea which account to add it to.

Answer (score 0):

would the feature under

> other calendars

```
    >import by URL
```

be what you are looking for?

provided your URL always points to the up to date calendar your google calendar will always be up to date (down to the synch frequency of google calendar) and you or anyone who you shared you google calendar url with will have access to it

Comment: Thanks for your reply oberron. What I am looking for is. I have created ".ical" file with the valid data. And its working fine, If I add the file by Import or by Add Url from the google calender settings it is adding to my gogole calender. Is there any way to generate the calender events dynamically when I created the .ics file. Or any link with the option Add to calender which will check for the login and after that redirect to calender to add the event.